# Prevent materializecss dropdown to close when clicking inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, materialize

I am using Materialize.css for current project, and I have dropdown with some input forms inside it.

Dropdown has option to close by:

- clicking outside of `.dropdown-content`
- clicking inside of `.dropdown-content`
- clicking on `.dropdown-button`

What I need is to **not close** when clicking inside of it, because i need to be able to fill in input forms and other actions.

Here is simple [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGxAwG)

Comment: You shouldn't use a dropdown at all for this type of action. A dropdown is meant to select one item from a list of items, not compose entire forms. A better alternative is to make a button that presents a form modal or emulates a dropdown as needed.

Comment: This has been fixed as of version 1.0.0. When initializing the dropdown, you can specify closeOnClick: false. https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html#options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick solution would be to stopPropagation on click on content wrapper.

```
$('.dropdown-button + .dropdown-content').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I would avoid using 'dropdown' for this particular use-case.
But if you want to stick to it just apply the snippet above.

Comment: Works like champ. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example:

```
$('#first_name').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //Do whatever you want
});
```

to avoid the event generated by the input `first_name` from propagating. The dropdown will not detect it so it will not be closed.

Comment: anything more general? :/ Because I have lots of element  inside dropdowns. I tried to put `.dropdown-content` instead of `#first_name` but then I can't click on some buttons at all.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you can't click them? I tried using `.dropdown-content` and assigning an id `#hi` to the second `<a>` on your example. Then I tried to press the button with `$('#hi').click(function (event) {
    console.log('kkk') 
});` defined and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

use this "closeOnClick : false" on dropdown initializing

```
$(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown({
    closeOnClick : false          
});
```